# Decorators, calling functions without parenthesis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, decorator, python-decorators

I'm teaching myself how to code with the help of some online tutorials. I've encountered "decorators", I can seem to understand how it works but something bothers me. Here's the code given:

```
def decor(func):
    def wrap():
        print("-----------")
        func()
        print("-----------")
    return wrap

def print_text():
    print("Hello World")

decorated = decor(print_text)
decorated()

output:
-----------
Hello World
-----------
```

The things that I want to understand are:

- Why do you have to call "return wrap" instead of "return wrap()"? Whereas if you don't you'll get a "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.
- When I assigned the value of decorated variable. How come I also had to use "print_text" rather than "print_text()" whereas it'll raise the same TypeError if I do?
- When I used the variable "decorated". Why did I have to call it like a function (adding () at the end). When I call it using "decorated" or "print(decorated)" it says something completely different?

Sorry for the dumb questions. But I'm just starting out so please bear with me. Also please make your responses beginner-friendly. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python, just about everything is an object. Functions are *objects too*. You can reference them by their name:

```
>>> def print_text():
...     print("Hello World")
...
>>> print_text   # **no** call here, this is just referencing the object
<function print_text at 0x10e3f1c80>
>>> print_text() # With a call, so now we *run* the function
Hello World
```

Adding `()` to the name told Python to call the function, which caused it to actually execute the function body, without the call, it is just showing you what the name references.

You can assign function objects to other names too. Those other names can still be called, invoking the function:

```
>>> other_name = print_text
>>> other_name
<function print_text at 0x10e3f1c80>
>>> other_name()
Hello World
```

So `other_name` is just another reference to the same object, and adding `()` (a call expression) causes the function object to be executed. `print_text()` and `other_name()` do the exact same thing, run the code inside the function.

That's what name `func` inside of `decor()` refers to; it is a reference to the same function object. You passed it in with `decor(print_text)`. Only later on, inside `wrapper()` the expression `func()` calls that function object. If you passed in `print_text()` instead, you'd pass in the `None` object that function returned, and `None` can't be called:

```
>>> return_value = print_text()
Hello World
>>> return_value is None
True
>>> return_value()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Next, `return wrapper` returns the newly created `wrapper` function object to the caller. If you did `return wrapper()`, you'd return the *result of the function*, not the function object itself.

The whole point of a decorator is to replace the original function object with a new object that does extra stuff, which is why a decorator returns that replacement object (in your example `wrapper`) so that in future when you call `decorated()`, you call that wrapper function doing something extra before and after calling the original function (via the `func` name, which references `print_text()`).

So what `decor(some_function)` does is return a *new* function object, one that'll print something, call the function object that was passed in, then print something else. That new function object can then be used to replace the old function object.